# pass prop from map method into parent component

Tags: reactjs

I have created two components: `Counter` and `Counters`. In `Counters`, I have four headings. I want to display them by the map method. I created a map method and map heading and pass into another component like `this.props.children`. It maps into heading but it displays all heading in one: first, second, and third. I want to display into another line each line consist of one heading not all the heading at a time
this is my `Counter` code. Here I pass as props:

```
class Counter extends Component {
    state={
        value:this.props.value,
        heading:this.props.children
    };
   
    render() {
        console.log(this.props)
        return (
            <div>
                {this.state.heading}
                <span className={this.getbadgesClasses()}>{this.formatcount()}</span>
                <button onClick={this.getProductId} className="btn btn-secondary btn-sm">increment</button>
            </div>
        );
    }
    handleIncrement=(product)=>{
        console.log(product)
        return this.setState({value: this.state.value + 1})
    }
    getProductId=()=>{
        this.handleIncrement({id:1});
    }
    getbadgesClasses(){
        let classes =" badge m-2 badge-";
        classes +=  this.state.value === 0 ? "warning" : "primary";
        return classes;
    }
    formatcount(){
        
        return this.state.value === 0 ? 'Zero' : this.state.value;
    }
}
```

this is my `Counters` component. Here, I map `headings`

```
class Counters extends Component {
    state={
        counters:[
            {id:1, value:4},
            {id:2, value:3},
            {id:3, value:2},
            {id:4, value:1}
        ],
        headings:[
            {head:'first'},
            {head:'second'},
            {head:'third'},
            {head:'forth'}
        ]

    }
    
    render() {
        
        return (
            <div>
           {this.state.counters.map(m=>
           <Counter key={m.id} value={m.value}>
               {this.state.headings.map(m=>m.head)}
           </Counter>) }


            </div>

        );
    }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do I understand it correctly, that you want the first line to have "first", second to have "second" etc. as heading?

In that case, use the index in the map function to display the correct heading.

```
{
  this.state.counters.map((m, index) =>
    <Counter key={m.id} value={m.value}>
      {this.state.headings[index].head}
    </Counter>
  ) 
}
```

Or, put the heading inside each counter object.

```
counters:[
    {id:1, value:4, head: 'first'},
    {id:2, value:3, head: 'second'},
    {id:3, value:2, head: 'third'},
    {id:4, value:1, head: 'fourth'}
],
```

And use it like this.

```
{
  this.state.counters.map((m) =>
    <Counter key={m.id} value={m.value}>
      {m.head}
    </Counter>
  ) 
}
```